# Java method to recursively add each integer in an array to all of the elements following it?

Tags: java, arrays

For example if I have an array of ints as a parameter to my method, my method needs to return an array of ints where each element is the sum of all the elements following it.
Example:
parameter is [5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 1] I need to return [24, 19, 13, 6, 4, 1]

I have a written a helper method that correctly adds an index to all of the ones after it here:

```
public static int sum(int[] array, int index) {
    if (index == array.length) {
        return array[array.length-1];
    } else {
        return array[index] + sum(array, index + 1);
    }
}
```

This all works as it should, but I'm having trouble with the original method here:

```
public int[] reverseCumulative(int[] numbers) {
    int[] temp = new int[numbers.length];
    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        return temp;
    }
    else {
    temp[numbers.length-1] = sum(numbers, numbers.length);
    numbers = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length - 1);
    reverseCumulative(numbers);
    return temp;

    }
}
```

The output here is [0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 1]. I understand that this is most likely due to the fact I'm creating a new int[] temp every time I call the reverseCumulative method within itself, but I am completely lost and any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Edit: Forgot to add, I am not allowed to use any loops.

Comment: I guessed `sum(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}, 0)` should return 10 or 9, but it [returned 14](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HtNoa9gOFsdJ3xy0). Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: What about a double `for` loop to go through all the elements?

Comment: @Error404 You will need only one `for` loop if recursion is not required.

Comment: @MikeCAT What do you mean when you say `recursion`?

Comment: @Error404 To call a method from the method itself to do something. For example, `int fact(int a){return a<2?1:a*fact(a-1);}`

Comment: @MikeCAT I did not know that. Thank you for the point!

Comment: I forgot to add, this is an assignment and we can't use any loops.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a new array each time you call the reverseCumulative method, you should use the sum method as a helper method inside the reverseCumulative method so that you are still using recursion. For example,

```
public int[] reverseCumulative(int[] numbers) {
    int[] temp = new int[numbers.length];
    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        return temp;
    }
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            temp[i] = sum(numbers,i);
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

This way, each element in temp equals a sum of integers in the numbers array depending on which iteration it is currently on. In the first iteration, temp[0] = the sum of all the ints in numbers. In the second iteration, temp[1] = the sum of all the ints in numbers except the first int and so on. However, the way the sum method is written right now, it adds the last element twice so here's a simple fix,

```
public static int sum(int[] array, int index) {
    if (index == array.length-1) {
        return array[array.length-1];
    } else {
        return array[index] + sum(array, index + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
public static int sum(final int[] target, final int[] source, int index) {
    if (index >= source.length - 1)
        return source[index];

    return target[index] = source[index] + sum(target, source, index + 1);
}

public static int[] reverseCulmulative(final int[] array) {
    final int[] target = array.clone();
    sum(target, array, 0);
    return target;
}
```